# Is the image of a basis, a basis?

Tags: general-topology

(EDITED)
$(X,\tau_X),(Y,\tau_Y)$ topological spaces
$f : X \rightarrow Y$ a bijective, continuous function.

If $\tau_C$ is a basis of $\tau_X$, is $f(\tau_C)$ a basis of $\tau_Y$?

If $\tau_B$ is a basis of $\tau_Y$, is $f^{-1}(\tau_B)$ a basis of $\tau_X$?

thanks

Comment: Think of how degenerate a continuous map $f$ can be, e.g. if $f$ is constant.

Comment: Bijective will still not be enough, consider for example $X=Y$ (as sets) but let $\tau_X=\mathcal {P}(X)$ be the discrete topology and $\tau_Y$ be the trivial topology. Let $f:X\to Y, f(x)=x$

Comment: ok thanks, then is it true for homeomorphisms?

Comment: Yes, it is true for homeomorphisms.